# How to use assign html select value to a php variable

Tags: php

```
 <select name="parentgroup" type="text" id="select2" onchange="this.form.submit();">
 <?php
 echo "<option value=\"0\">All Users</option>";
 $result = mysql_query("select * from login WHERE stato=1");
 while ($myresults = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {

      $username = $myresults['user_name'];
      echo "<option value=\"".$username."\" "; 
      echo $username== $parentgroupid ? " selected" : ""; 
      echo ">".$username."</option>";
 }
 ?>
 </select>
```

Hi...am supposed to use the first element in `<select>` which is `<option value=\"0\">All Users</option>` to fetch values from a mysql database.

I want to now how you can assign this to a variable and use it just like `$parentgroupid`

Comment: Use a form and send it to an php script?

Comment: i already have a form......i need to assignthe first entry to a variable

Answer (score 1):

When you submit the form (which presumably exists since you are referencing it from your JavaScript): Get the value from `$_GET['name_of_form_control']` in the document referenced by the `action` attribute of the form.

Comment: The first element in the droplist is just assigned as 'All Users' while the rest of the users are populated from the database....ihave already assigned the database entries to the variable $parentgroupid but i also need to assign the first element which is used to later to query the database and fetch diffrent values from the rest

Answer (score 1):

When you submit the form, depending on the `method` specified in the form ("GET" or "POST"), the value will be in either the `$_GET` or `$_POST` arrays on the page to which you are submitting. You can retrieve the value by name (the name of the control):

```
$parentgroupid = $_GET['parentgroup'];
```

or

```
$parentgroupid = $_POST['parentgroup'];
```

Comment: Or `$_REQUEST['parentgroup']`

Comment: @rink.attendant.6: Yes, although using `$_REQUEST` as a catch-all is generally frowned upon due to security issues.

Comment: I agree, but in this case we don't know if they're using GET or POST.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 Cory has compensated for this by including an example for both of the global scoped arrays

Comment: The first element in the droplist is just assigned as 'All Users' while the rest of the users are populated from the database....ihave already assigned the database entries to the variable $parentgroupid but i also need to assign the first element which is used to later to query the database and fetch diffrent values from the rest

Comment: @julihx: But the `0` for "All Users" will end up in the same arrays as described above upon form submission. You will have to test for whether `$parentgroupid == 0` somewhere in your code to know whether they picked the default option or one of the others. If you're going to clash with a database ID, pick a different value or no value at all for the "All Users" option, and test accordingly on the server side. If you're having trouble submitting on change with the default value selected, then you may need to trigger the change programmatically.